# "proud owner"? who are you?

Tags: meaning

I found an example sentence that is "I am now the proud owner of the first trading post". but I don't know means of the proud owner. According to [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Proud%20Owner), it means

> Any customer who purchases something that is non refundable.

And in example it means proud. Is this an idiomatic?

Comment: What dictionary site is this?

Comment: I suspect you got this definition from Urban Dictionary. UD is crowdsourced and contains a large proportion of joke definitions: ignore it. "Proud owner" means exactly what it says: you own the first trading post, and you are proud of owning it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clarify the definition you cite -- it is an example of the use of "proud owner" as sarcasm (and that "humorous" usage is common).

Max's answer gives the real definition, actually being proud to own something.  The normal implication is that the item is special to you (like your first car), or something difficult to acquire (so ownership is an accomplishment).

Something that is non-refundable is something you purchased and for which returns are not accepted.  Focusing on that aspect implies that it is something you might well want to return, but you're stuck with it, like it or not.

The humor is in framing something you're stuck with as a cherished possession or accomplishment.

Answer (score 8):

There is no secret meaning here. *Proud* simply means *proud* in the usual sense.

> [proud](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/proud)
>   feeling satisfaction and pleasure because of something that you have achieved, possess, or are a part of:
>   He’s very proud of his daughters.
>   The company is proud of its environmental record.
>   [+ to infinitive] I am proud to have played a part in what this team achieved.
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

Urban Dictionary can be a good source of definitions for **slang**, but in general you should be wary of the entries. Often, the entries are jokes and not meant to be taken literally.  Just in case, you can find a list of reputable sources at the meta post [Resources for learning English: Dictionaries](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#739).

With that in mind, being a proud owner of something does not mean that the item is not refundable. That might be the case, but that is not what the expression means. That entry was a joke. One interpretation is that if you considering whether or not something is refundable, then you are unlikely to be happy with that purchase. If you're not satisfied with it, you can't possibly be *proud* of it. :D

In any case, *proud owner* simply means that you are proud to own that thing because the thing is remarkable, noteworthy, or special.
The "first trading post" seems like a noteworthy purchase, so saying that you're the proud owner of that is appropriate.

Here are a few examples I found online:

> - Microsoft Billionaire Is the **Proud Owner** of The World's Biggest Airplane, and Just Look at This Thing
>     ([Maxim](https://www.maxim.com/rides/worlds-biggest-airplane-2017-6))
> - Dexter the three-foot long giant rabbit is shown off by his **proud owner**, as the adorable bunny is on his way to becoming the world's biggest bunny.
>     ([Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/video/news/video-1470021/Dexter-three-foot-long-giant-rabbit-shown-proud-owner.html))
> - A Boston man who was once a **proud owner** of a 7-Eleven convenience store has turned his back on the company and opened his own shop across the street. He’s calling it 6-Twelve.
>     ([Global News](http://globalnews.ca/news/3498088/boston-7-eleven-franchise-owner-pushed-out-by-corporate-opens-6-twelve-in-revenge/))

Comment: Note that "proud owner" can also be sarcastic, to indicate something trivial (I am now the proud owner of a six-pack of beer) or unwanted (I am now the proud owner of a falling-down building).

Comment: I think the joke is that someone who has bought something non-refundable has to feel like they got their money's worth as there's "no going back", so they will likely insist on being proud of owning it to their friends to try to justify the purchase to themselves, much to their friends' annoyance.